# Join list and string into a tuple of four elements

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list of nums:

```
[18, 9, 7]
```

and a string:

```
line = 'random text.'
```

I must join these two into a tuple of four elements shown below:

```
(18, 9, 7, 'random text.')
```

So far I have tried ***nums.join(line)*** but this does not work

*How can I do this?*

Note:
I would prefer not using tuple() or importing anything. simplest most brute force method possible ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack the list within the tuple declaration:

```
nums = [18, 9, 7]
line = 'random text.'
combined_tuple = (*nums, line)
print(combined_tuple)
```

**Output:**

```
(18, 9, 7, 'random text.')
```

Answer (score 1):

The absolute simplest method is the following:

```
lst = [18, 9, 7]
line = 'random text.'
tup = (lst[0], lst[1], lst[2], line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this

```py
nums = [18, 9, 7]
line = 'random text.' 

result = (*[item for item in nums], line)

print(result)
```